# Laravel: Consulta con múltiples with

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$items = RequestItems::where('requests.user_id', '=', $user->id)
      ->orderBy('requests.id', 'desc')
      ->with(['item', 'image', 'gratitude', 'item.user', 'gratitude.gratitude_image'])
      ->paginate(10);
```

De donde obtengo esto:

[image]

Intento acceder desde Blade a los campos en gratitude_image en un @foreach($items as $item) pero no me da::

```
{{$item->gratitude->gratitude_image[0]}}
```

Pero no me trae la información. Por favor ayuda…

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error?

Comment: `gratitude_image` es un array o un objeto?

Comment: Ese es otro problema que tengo, me da error el laravel.log y no me deja ver que es lo que esta pasando. gratitude_image es una tabla relacionada a traves de su id con la tabla gratitude.

Comment: Si pero a lo que voy es que si pones [0] es como si indicaras acceder al valor del índice 0 y si el resultado Shi no es una colección sino un objeto por eso el fallo, entonces repito la pregunta ahí obtienes una colección o un objeto?

Comment: Obtengo una colección

Comment: Ok y cuando ejecutas esa consulta sake algo? Algún error?

Comment: La consulta no me da error, muestra el JSON de la imagen. Me da error en el blade cuando quiero mostrar esto {{$item->gratitude->gratitude_image[0]}}. Pero no se cual es dicho error porque estoy trabajando en producción y el laravel.log da este error:  UnexpectedValueException

The stream or file "/var/www/virtuales/fundacionvalora/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Dale permisos de escritura al log y ahí sabremos con exactitud que está fallando

Comment: Es que he tratado de darle permisos pero no me deja. Me da este error en FileZIlla: Error: set attrs for /storage/logs: permission denied

Comment: es correcto es cosa de permisos, para que te imprima el error, porque no descargas el proyecto y lo haces localmente_?

Comment: Al parecer no siempre tienes una gratitude image, por lo cual no puede encontrar el dato, antes debes validar que exista.

    {{ $item->gratitude->gratitude_image[0] ?? '' }}